# Tuple reflection crashing on iOS 7?

Tags: ios, swift, reflection, ios7, tuples

Since the last update of my app (using new iOS SDK 9.3) tuple reflection crashes on iOS 7.
This code

```
let t = (5,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,7)
let m = Mirror(reflecting: t)
```

generates an "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" on iOS 7 (and maybe only 32-bit devices as I got reports only from iPhone 4, 4S, 5 and iPad 2, Mini, 3).

The same code works fine on iOS 9 and that

Am I missing something? Is this a bug at Apple?
What could be an alternative to make this work? (I'm using tuple reflection to turn the machine field of utsname() into a String)

Comment: There is no reflection in Swift, you are looking into undocumented functionality. Do not use `reflect` and mirrors in production!

Comment: It is documented, see [Mirror Structure Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Mirror_Structure/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/struct/s:Vs6Mirror).

Comment: "Mirrors are used by playgrounds and the debugger." This is not for production code. Reflection will come to Swift maybe in the future.

Comment: I find it strange that Apple allows to publish an app using them then. I understand performance considerations but for my use case it's irrelevant and by the way the exact same code was working on iOS 7 before I update the sdk to 9.3.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the documentation of the mentioned feature says it's for playground / debugging use.